# hook_menu implementation producing error page

Tags: routes

I am trying to create a new module implementing hook_menu, to render a page on my company's web site, which I have taken over from the external firm who designed it. There are other modules that use the hook_menu mechanism successfully on the site.

However, when I create my module and try to access my new page, I get a message indicating "Error. The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.", with no real indication of what the error is.

Here is my code:

```
<?php

function customer_stories_menu(){
    $items['test'] = array(
        'title' => 'Products Display',
        'title callback' => 'customer_stories_title',
        'page callback' => 'customer_stories_page',
        'access arguments' => array('access content'),
        'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    );

    return $items;
}

function customer_stories_page() {  
    return "Test 123";
}

function customer_stories_title() {
    return "Title";
}
```

I have made sure that I cleared the cache after putting the code in place. Could something in the site be preventing new hook_menu pages from working?

I should also mention that I first tried creating a new view page to get to the data I wanted to display, but I also got a non-descript error page when I tried to access the defined URL for the page. The two issues may be related. Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

I've got this noted down as my starting point for a  module .

```
function helloworld_menu() {

$menu['helloworld/hello'] = array(
    'title' => 'Hello World',
    'page callback' => 'helloworld_hello',
'access callback' => TRUE,
);
   return $menu;
  }

function helloworld_hello() {
   return 'Hello World';
 };
```

do you still get an error if you take it back to this point.

Comment: Yes, I still get an error with this basic code. Doing some tests on a brand new install in parallel, the code works perfectly fine on a clean install, pointing to something preventing this from working on the site where I am trying to implement this.

Comment: I took the extreme route of deactivating all modules on my site and bringing them back in one by one. The culprit is a module called PHP Filter. When enabled, my custom hook_menu page does not work. When disabled, it displays as expected. Going to see if there is a configuration page for this plugin that needs to be edited. Any familiarity with this module causing this type of issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had code in one of my blocks that was causing an error. It was missing a condition to exit when getting called on a new page.